# multiple attachments are sent with phpmailer, I need to save to server only PDF's

Tags: php, server

I have an issue with one page of a rather large application. The page has a form that attaches files from the user and emails them with PHPMailer. I now need to add the ability to save only those attachments that are PDF's.  I have included the section that needs tweeking. the new section in between the lines of asterisks.

```
//Handle the files
$total = count($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    $name = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$i];
    $path = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $type = $_FILES['uploadfile']['type'][$i];
    $mail->AddAttachment($path,$name);
 //*************************************************************************************
// NEW PDF CHECK HERE
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ($ext == '.pdf'){
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'][$i], "path/to/file/{$_FILES['uploadfile']['name']}")){
            $pdfquery = "INSERT INTO reports (case_id, user_id, filename, upload_date, dept_id) VALUES ('$case_id', '$user', '{$_FILES['uploadfile']['name']}', CURDATE(), '$dept_id')";
            $pdfresult = mysqli_query($dbc, $pdfquery) or trigger_error("Query: $pdfquery\n<br>MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

            if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1){
                echo 'PDF Case Report Saved.<br><br>';
            } else {
                echo 'report failed to save to database.';

            }//END affected rows
     }  // END move report.
} // END $ext check.

//************************************************************************************* 
    } // END for loop.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply check mime type, not the extention (.pdf), since one can upload a PHP file named evil.pdf to your server or someone might upload a pdf having a different extention. I show you just the part relevant to the question.

```
$total = count($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    //Attach the file anyway
    $name = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$i];
    $path = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $type = $_FILES['uploadfile']['type'][$i];
    $mail->AddAttachment($path,$name);
    if (finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) !== 'application/pdf') {
        //file does not have the expected mime type, possibly this is a hack
        //attempt, therefore we ignore the file
        continue;
    }
    //If the program reaches this point, then the file is PDF
}
```

Comment: I guess I should have said that this part of the script is only accessed by Board of Directors level employees, and that all files needs to be sent in the email, but only the PDF is to be saved.

Comment: @StephenThompson, have you tried the suggestion? Is it solving your problem? If not, what is the problem you still have?

Comment: The files can't just be ignored, they all need to be attached. 
     if != pdf{  attach }
     if  = pdf{ attach AND save to server}

Comment: @StephenThompson, understood. I have edited my answer. Basically: you need to attach the files before you check for pdf mime type and continue.